# Do banks need a foreign branch to access a derivatives market (e.g.) London

Tags: banking, markets, derivatives, regulation

I would be very interested to know whether banks (e.g. Santander, Deutsche Bank, etc.) need a foreign branch in a country (e.g. UK - London) to access the derivatives market in this country.

Would this branch then fall under the regulation of the country where the market place is, in this case the FCA in London?

Any help, links, references are very much appreciated!

Best

lexjfm